# Why global variables are null in a jni function?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use a variable which holds a pointer to a function. The pointer is loaded from JNI_OnLoad Function by using `dlsym` and calling it, but I ended up getting `NULL POINTER DEREFERENCE` which shows that my `SendCode` is `NULL` inside any JNI Function (Except JNI_OnLoad).

I have tried initiating `SendCode` again in the jni function with a global pointer of `dlopen` but the global pointer of `dlopen` itself is always NULL  because of this issue. I also have tried checking if the `SendCode` is not null in the jni function but it makes `SendCode` never called because of it always null.

```cpp
void(*SendCode)(int code);

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    vm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);

    void* handle = dlopen("libapi.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if(handle != NULL)
    {
        SendCode = (void(*)(int))dlsym(handle, "SendCode"); 
        if(SendCode == NULL)
        {
            ALOGI("Error: SendCode is NULL!");
        }
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myapp_MainActivity_onSendCode(JNIEnv*, jclass, jint code)
{
    SendCode(code);
}
```

Comment: There's no log if `handle` ends up being `NULL`, so have you verified that that isn't the case?

Comment: Well the `handle` is always not  `NULL`  because I did a previous check before.

Comment: And you did check that libapi.so indeed contains an exported symbol named "SendCode"?

Comment: @user2543253 Yes it is exists. I can tell you that `SendCode` is not `NULL` in other function else than JNI function.

Comment: Are you sure the null pointer dereference is caused by `SendCode` being `NULL`? Or could it be that the problem is somewhere *inside* `SendCode`. What if you explicitly compare `SendCode == NULL` in `onSendCode()`?. If you can run through a debugger, then you could break in `onLoad` and set a watchpoint on `SendCode` to see when it changes. Another reason for a crash could be that your library got unloaded (for whatever reason) and thus `SendCode` now points to code that is no longer in memory.

Comment: @DanielJunglas I'm pretty sure it's from there since the Errors in logcat itself shows exception on function `Java_com_myapp_MainActivity_onSendCode`, and I would say no that if the library got unloaded because it has a thread running.

Comment: Even if you are sure, better to add a check and explicitly `abort()` if `SendCode` is null. Just to be safe. Also, what does `ALOGI` do? Will it abort the application? If not then I suggest to also replace this with a hard `abort` for debugging. Maybe the symbol is not found but `ALOGI` fails to report that (for whatever reason). If you `abort()` instead then you will no exactly what is going on.

Comment: Two other things that may go wrong here: 1. The symbol is in the library but the library does not export the symbol. 2. You are compiling this with C++ and the function is not marked as `extern "C"`. Then the name of the function in the library will be mangled and you will have to look up the *mangled* named. You can check by running `nm libapi.so | grep SendCode`. What does this output? Does it show the cleaned or the mangled name? Does it show that the symbol is public?

Comment: It would be a good idea to do some debugging with gdb

Comment: @DanielJunglas ALOGI is a macro for writing a log to logcat. And yes `SendCode` symbol itself clear (It's `SendCode`). I'm gonna try @Dmitry's solution by using dummy local function and see if it's still NULL.

Answer (score 0):

most likely it's because symbol `SendCode` in `libapi.so` is either itself a NULL, or not found:

> ... If the symbol is not found, in the specified library or any of the
>   libraries that were automatically loaded by dlopen() when that library
>   was loaded, dlsym() returns NULL. (The search performed by dlsym() is
>   breadth first through the dependency tree of these libraries.) Since
>   the value of the symbol could actually be NULL (so that a NULL return
>   from dlsym() need not indicate an error), the correct way to test for
>   an error is to call dlerror() to clear any old error conditions, then
>   call dlsym(), and then call dlerror() again...

you can easily verify it by init'ing your pointer `SendCode` with a dummy function (e.g. producing some output) and then run it as per your code flow. If you get the segfault with a null-pointer dereference again - you know it's in that assignment (from `dlsym`) the NULL is returned.

Comment: Note that the code in `JNI_OnLoad` explicitly checks whether `SendCode` is `NULL` produces some error if so.

Comment: yes, I took as pertaining to following of OP's explanation "...I also have tried checking if the SendCode is not null in the jni function but it makes SendCode never called because of it always null"